# Ubuntu Server installation fails with missing packages

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 in a Hyper-V VM, but the installation fails with a missing package error.

Specifically, I get a 404 error when trying to download `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.16_all.deb` during installation.

I also get a 404 when I try and load that URL in Chrome so this is obviously a valid error. How do I get the installer past this point?

I've downloaded and verified the latest ISO (18.04.4) and the error persists.

Any help is appreciated!

[Installation Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vPVr.png)

Comment: I've verified the file and re-downloaded and verified again. I have the same issue with the 18.04.2 and 18.04.4 images. I'm trying to boot directly from the ISO in a VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a 404 error when trying to browse the link you described, is because you typed the link wrong: you forgot to insert /l/ between /main and /linux-firmware, so it should be: `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.173.16_all.deb`

According to your screenshot - your installer tries to connect the US archive (and inserts the correct link).

I also verified the release and package files and directories at the repository, and they all seem to be correct.

So about your connection failure: notice that you can't even connect the server, while a 404 indicates that you got to the server but the requested url was wrong.
That leads me to think that from some reason while installing the OS your internet connection from the guest or the host machine goes down, or getting blocked from some reason.
Ubuntu server install always tries to connect to web to get the latest packages and install the system online by default.
If it managed to connect, the whole install will rely on Ubuntu's online repositories.

Things you can do besides debugging your network: just install the OS from the cd itself (ISO in your case).
Block the web access while installing the OS.

The ISO contains all the needed components for your install, and the installer should use them.
After that, you can connect the web and preform updates.

Edit: I had the time so I quickly downloaded a server 18.04.4 ISO and installed it using the us.ubuntu repo. The installation worked.
My hypervisor was vmware ws 15.

Comment: I guess it's been a long week... The IPS was blocking that one download for some reason. Whitelisted it, works great. *face palm* Thank you for your help!